# How to create MULTIPLE boxes where you copy text to clipboard on button click?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the button to copy the text from the text field. Try to paste the text (e.g. ctrl+v) afterwards in a different window, to see the effect.</p>

<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I got this code from w3schools website, here is the link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_copy_clipboard

I'm super beginner, can u please help me create multiple boxes so which ever box you click on it will copy to clipboard that text?

I tried duplicating the same code and changed the `myInput` but it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap each box within a `div`. Then, you need to pass `event` object to `onclick` function of each button. Since the text input is immediately followed by a button, you can use `previousElementSibling` method, which selects the previous sibling of it (which is input).

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  var copyText = e.target.previousElementSibling;
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click on the button to copy the text from the text field. Try to paste the text (e.g. ctrl+v) afterwards in a different window, to see the effect.</p>

  <div>
    <input type="text" value="Hello World" class="myInput">
    <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Copy text</button>
  </div>


  <div>
    <input type="text" value="Input 2" class="myInput">
    <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Copy text</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" value="Input 3" class="myInput">
    <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Copy text</button>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can achieve is by using `this` object. I have modified your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <div >
        <input type="text" value="Hello World 1" id="myInput" >
        <button onclick="myFunction(this.parentNode.children[0])">Copy text</button>
    </div>

    <div >
        <input type="text" value="Hello World 2" id="myInput" >
        <button onclick="myFunction(this.parentNode.children[0])">Copy text</button>
    </div>

    <div >
        <input type="text" value="Hello World 3" id="myInput" >
        <button onclick="myFunction(this.parentNode.children[0])">Copy text</button>
    </div>


    <script>
    function myFunction(previousSibling) {

      var copyText = previousSibling;
      copyText.select();
      copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
      document.execCommand("copy");
      alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

What is happening here?

- We make use of `this` object, which refers to context of current element, which is button after we click it.
- Then we find the parent of it (parent of button) using `this`
- Then from parent we get the corresponding child (input field)
  which is `children[0]`
- This child is then passed to the function
- Above steps repeat for any button click